# Обработка больших изображений

Tags: android, java, изображения, bitmap

Всем привет!

Столкнулся с такой задачей: моя программа должна открыть изображение (в большинстве случаев это будут `jpeg`/`png` файлы размером более 3 Мб), на лету изменить его и сохранить. Я пока что надумал такой алгоритм: открываем изображение, с помощью `BitmapRegionDecoder` в цикле считываем изображение по кусочкам (например квадраты `250х250`), обрабатываем эти куски. А вот как сохранить эти куски обратно в новый файл? Отрисовать все на `Canvas`, а потом сохранить его - не вариант, так как точно будет `OutOfMemory` из-за больших размеров картинки. Есть ли что-нибудь вроде `BitmapRegionEncoder`? :)

Comment: а про picasso думал?

Comment: @Gorets, это библиотека для загрузки и вывода изображений на экран, если мне не изменяет память. С загрузкой у меня всё нормально, вывод на экран мне не нужен. А вот с сохранением возник вопрос.

Comment: Ручками написать чтение/запись. И лучше в C++)

Comment: @SuperCreeper можно поинтересоваться, как именно вы изменяете картинку?)
Судя из задачи BitmapRegionDecoder не особо подходит для решения, т.к. не отдает ничего кроме кусочков изображения, а это срач в памяти на лету (кроме того, что картинка висит в памяти, так еще нужно собрать измененную и сохранить...). Смотря какие изменения происходят с картинкой, можно поколдовать над inputstream-ом как вариант, но нужно знать, что именно изменить нужно.

Comment: @Nuclominus, я хочу шифровать изображения (шум, замена и инвертирование цветов). Я вот и подумал, что делать такие операции лучше всего с маленькими частями изображения.

Comment: не знаю как png, но jpeg кодируется клетками 8х8